# Transform string column to vector column Spark DataFrames

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have a Spark dataframe that looks as follows:

```
+-----------+-------------------+
|     ID    |     features      |
+-----------+-------------------+
|   18156431|(5,[0,1,4],[1,1,1])|
|   20260831|(5,[0,4,5],[2,1,1])|   
|   91859831|(5,[0,1],[1,3])    |
|  206186631|(5,[3,4,5],[1,5])  |
|  223134831|(5,[2,3,5],[1,1,1])|
+-----------+-------------------+
```

In this dataframe the features column is a sparse vector. In my scripts I have to save this DF as file on disk. When doing this, the features column is saved as as text column: example `"(5,[0,1,4],[1,1,1])"`. 
When importing again in Spark the column stays string, as you could expect. How can I convert the column back to (sparse) vector format?

Comment: Which version of Spark? Which vector class you want to get (`ML` / `MLib`) ? How do you read this data?

Comment: Spark version = 1.6.2. Preferably a ML vector (but you can explain for both). I use the following code to read the data: `DF = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true', delimiter=delimiter).load('file://'+path).drop('')`

Comment: There is no ML Vector in 1.6 so it makes things simple :)

Comment: It can also be a MLLib vector or any other type of (sparse) vector :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not particularly efficient (it would be a good idea to use a format that preserves types) due to UDF overhead but you can do something like this:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

df = sc.parallelize([
    (18156431, "(5,[0,1,4],[1,1,1])") 
]).toDF(["id", "features"])

parse = udf(lambda s: Vectors.parse(s), VectorUDT())
df.select(parse("features"))
```

Please note this doesn't port directly to 2.0.0+ and `ML` `Vector`. Since ML vectors don't provide `parse` method you'd have to parse to `MLLib` and use `asML`:

```
parse = udf(lambda s: Vectors.parse(s).asML(), VectorUDT())
```

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example code of asML in python and Spark 2.0.2? Should I put the asML in a udf?